# Howe to select default option from multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I am running a listings page using WordPress which uses a filter to filter by region. In order to filter by Province (State), the Filter by Country first needs to be selected which will enable the Province (State) Filters.

This is tedious because I am only running the listings in one country (South Africa) so I would like the default select option for Filter by Country to be "South Africa" and then hide the container using CSS so the users would not need to have to select a country.

I have tried various JS/Jquery options using a plugin to add JS/HTML to pages on the site but nothing has worked so far. I'm hoping someone can offer a solution...[dev-tools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssny.jpg)

Comment: Please try to put your code into a text rather than an image so it would be easier for others trying to help.

Comment: Also, if the image goes away, the question will be meaningless. Please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also make sure you search. I bet this has been answered in some way.